# Where to get basic business info such as address and phone number?

Tags: data-request, business, address

I've read a few answers but they all have answers that have broken links or outdated info.

I need to find a way to get very basic information about businesses in the United States.  For example, let's say I want to get a list of all Subway restaurants in the USA.  I need their address, city, state, zip, and phone number.

At first I thought about using Google Places API for that, but they don't really allow anything on a mass scale like that.

Is there anywhere this data can be accessed for free? I could always create custom crawler to crawl their public restaurant locator tool, but since I need this information from hundreds of businesses, it would take a very long time and would be a maintenance nightmare since they change their websites or restaurant locator tools often.

This all seems like public information but I guess the question is whether it's available anywhere to be accessed easily.

Answer (score 2):

[OpenCorporates](https://opencorporates.com/) is the only open database of companies in the world that I am aware. They provide addresses and other data. Not sure if they have phone numbers. But I guess it is the best free, open option you have.

For example, [here you can find](https://opencorporates.com/companies?jurisdiction_code=&q=subway) all companies with the keyword Subways. You can filter it bases on the countries and states you want. Then download it as XML or JSON.